# Restoring Tensorflow model from .pbtxt and .meta files

Tags: tensorflow

I trained a model using `MonitoredTrainingSession()` with a checkpoint saver hook `tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook()` saving checkpoints every 1000 steps. After training the following files were created in the checkpoint directory:

```
events.out.tfevents.1511969396.cmle-training-master-ef2237c814-0-xn7pp
graph.pbtxt
model.ckpt-1.meta
model.ckpt-1001.meta
model.ckpt-2001.meta
model.ckpt-3001.meta
model.ckpt-4001.meta
model.ckpt-4119.meta
```

I want to restore the checkpoint but can't, here is my code (assuming the files above are in the directory `checkpoints`):

```
tf.train.import_meta_graph('checkpoints/model.ckpt-4139.meta')
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('./checkpoints/')
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

The problem is `ckpt` is `None`, I think I might be missing a file... What I am doing wrong.

This is how I save the checkpoints:

```
hooks=lists()
hooks.append(tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir=checkpoint_dir, save_steps=checkpoint_iterations)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter()):

        batch = model.input_fn(train_path, batch_size, epochs, 'train_queue')

        tensors = model.model_fn(batch, content_weight, style_weight, tv_weight, vgg_path, style_features,
                                 batch_size, learning_rate)

    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=target,
                                           is_chief=is_chief,
                                           checkpoint_dir=job_dir,
                                           hooks=hooks,
                                           save_checkpoint_secs=None,
                                           save_summaries_steps=None,
                                           log_step_count_steps=10) as sess:
        _ = sess.run(tensors)
       (...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Restoring the full checkpoint

[`tf.train.get_checkpoint_state`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_checkpoint_state) checks the `checkpoint` (no extension) file inside the directory you pass as parameter.
This file has usually a content similar to:

```
model_checkpoint_path: "model.ckpt-1"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model.ckpt-1"
```

If this file is missing, the function will return `None`.
Add a text file with that name and content to your model folder and you'll be able to restore using the code you already have.

**Very important note**: To restore this way you need **all** the checkpoint data, i.e., the three files: `.data-*`, `.meta` and `.index`.

#### Restoring just the graph

If, however, you're interested in restoring only the meta-graph, you can do so via [`import_meta_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph) as detailed in [the official TF guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph).

Note (from the definition of `import_meta_graph()`):

> This function takes a MetaGraphDef protocol buffer as input. If the
>   argument is a file containing a MetaGraphDef protocol buffer , it
>   constructs a protocol buffer from the file content. The function then
>   adds all the nodes from the graph_def field to the current graph,
>   recreates all the collections, and returns a saver constructed from
>   the saver_def field.

Using that saver won't work unless you have the `.index` and `.data-*` files in the same directory.

Comment: So I am missing the .index and .data-* files... Any idea why these were not generated by the CheckpointSaverHook()?

Comment: Can you show the part of your code where you save the model?

Comment: I have added how I save the checkpoints and kept how I define the graph because it might have something to with the problem

Comment: Your code looks OK, the `CheckpointSaverHook` takes care of handling the save properly, in theory.. I have no idea why you have the meta files, but no index or data...

Comment: You know what I see the problem, the CheckpointSaverHook() saver is empty, it is not saving any variable because the graph is empty when the hook is created... I had to look at the code of CheckpointSaverHook(), it initializes a saver and it allows it to be empty. Thanks for you help

Comment: Aha! Good catch!